# How to go through all items and than save them in a dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to load automatically a code from website.
I have a list with some names and want to go through every item. Go through the first item, make request, open website, copy the code/number from HTML (text in span) and than save this result in dictionary and so on (for all items).

I read from csv all lines and save them into a list. 
After this I make request to load HTML from a website, search the company and read the numbers from span.

My code:

```
with open(test_f, 'r') as file:
rows = csv.reader(file,
                  delimiter=',',
                  quotechar='"')
data = [data for data in rows]
print(data)
url_part1 = "http://www.monetas.ch/htm/651/de/Firmen-Suchresultate.htm?Firmensuche="
url_enter_company = [data for data in rows]
url_last_part = "&CompanySearchSubmit=1"

firma_noga = []
for data in firma_noga:
    search_noga = url_part1 + url_enter_company + url_last_part
    r = requests.get(search_noga)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    lii = soup.find_all("span")

    # print all numbers that are in a span
    numbers = [d.text for d in lii]
    print("NOGA Codes: ")
```

I want to get in dictionary the result, where the key should be the company name (item in a list) and the value should be the number that I read from the span:

```
dict = {"firma1": "620100", "firma2": "262000, 465101"}
```

Can some one help me, I am new at web scraping and python, and don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: what's currently wrong with your code?

Comment: please provide sample for `data` and `firma-noga` lists

Answer (score 0):

Split your string with regex and do your stuff depending on wether it is a number or not:

```
import re
for partial in re.split('([0-9]+)', myString):
    try:
        print(int(partial))
    except:
        print(partial + ' is not a number')
```

EDIT:

Well, `myString` is somewhat expected to be a string.
To get the text content of your spans as a string you should be able to use `.text` something like this:

```
spans = soup.find_all('span')
for span in spans:
    myString = span.text      #
    for partial in re.split('([0-9]+)', myString):
        try:
            print(int(partial))
        except:
            print(partial + ' is not a number')
```

Comment: I doesn't work on my script, here the error: for partial in re.split('([0-9]+)', firma_noga):
  File "re.py", line 203, in split
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: Thank you, but this is not what I really need. I need to know how to iterate over items in the list, get item in variable, make request, scrap the website and save the result in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Abstracting from my requirements in comments I think somethinfg like this should work for you:

```
firma_noga = ['firma1', 'firma2', 'firma3'] #NOT EMPTY as in your code!
res_dict = {}
for data in firma_noga:
    search_noga = url_part1 + url_enter_company + url_last_part
    r = requests.get(search_noga)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    lii = soup.find_all("span")
    for l in lii:
        if data not in res_dict:
            res_dict[data] = [l]
        else:
            res_dict[data].append(l)
```

Obviously this will work obviously if `firma-noga` won't be empty like in your code; and all the rest (your) parsing logic should be valid as well.

Comment: @haj, any feedback? was my answer helpful?

Comment: Hi @Dmitriy Fialkovskiy, thank you for you're answer, but it was not helpful.

Comment: so what was wrong with it? throwing error or something else?

Comment: The python list and dictionary were empty. I need as a result a dictionary which appends every item (company name) as a key and the number(s) as a value which I became from sraping the span. For e.g. `{"firma1": "620100", "firma2": "262000, 465101"}`

Comment: is `firma_noga` not empty when you launch script?

Comment: No, is not empty

Comment: didn't read attentively your reply first time. Ok, `firma_noga` is not empty when you lauch script. If so, then issue happens further, maybe when `search_noga` is created...I can't state it with 100% probability, because I'm not able to play with real `firma_noga` values. If you outlined a sample of them, that could help.